# How to get matched string part in SQL statement with many like checkes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible, to get matched string part in sql statement, which has many like statements.

```
SELECT fieldname
FROM table
WHERE content LIKE '%$val_1%'
   OR content LIKE '%$val_2%'
   OR content LIKE '%$val_3%'
   .
   .
   .
   OR content LIKE '%$val_n%'
```

i.e i need to get all that values`($val_1, or(and) $val_2 ...)`, which matched in content.

**example**

if my content is the following

```
content = 'this is my testing text'
```

and i have the following values, to check in like statements

```
$val_1 = 'thi';
$val_2 = 'esting';
$val_3 = 'other value, which not in my content';
```

I need to get the matched partts, i.e **"thi"** and **"esting"**, because they are matched in my content.

Comment: I don't get your question.....your query will run, if that is what you are asking

Comment: It sounds like you want to match the pattern val_[0-9]? If that's so, take a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html - RLIKE is probably what you are after.

Comment: I need to get one of ($val_1,...$val_n) values(or some of them), which cause my query to run. i.e that values, which are in my content.

Comment: Are you asking how to find which `$val_*` was matched in `content`?

Comment: I believe that @Syom is asking how to get which like operator(s) resulted in the match.  For example, did "content LIKE '%$val_1%'" evaluate to true? or did "content LIKE '%$val_2%'"? etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you're doing this in PHP, just use PHP to find out which bits matched after you get your rows back:

```
if (stripos($row['content'], $val_1) !== false) this bit matched!
if (stripos($row['content'], $val_2) !== false) this bit matched!
if (stripos($row['content'], $val_3) !== false) this bit matched!
```

Comment: `stripos()` would be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT fieldname, matchpart = '$val_1'
FROM table
WHERE content LIKE '%$val_1%'
UNION 
SELECT fieldname, matchpart = '$val_2'
FROM table
WHERE content LIKE '%$val_2%'
...
UNION 
SELECT fieldname, matchpart = '$val_n'
FROM table
WHERE content LIKE '%$val_n%'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query will return the column `fieldname` and `condX` where `condX` == 1 iff `content LIKE '%$val_X%'`, else 0.

Originally from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2261001/961455:

```
SELECT fieldname,
    `content` LIKE '%$val_1%' AS cond1,
    `content` LIKE '%$val_2%' AS cond2,
    ... ,
   `content` LIKE '%$val_n%' AS condn
FROM table
HAVING cond1 OR cond2 OR ... OR condn
```